# LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice

Since the latest upgrade of Libreoffice, some formulas in my spreadsheets are returning errors. This seems to affect formulas involving dates. I have tried several work-arounds to no avail.
Has anyone got a suggestion?

Comment: I recommend you **[edit]** with full details--at minimum, what version of LibreOffice you have now, what version you had before and how you upgraded (if you know), a complete and exact example of formulas that produce the problem so readers can try it out, and a description of what errors you get, including the *errors'* complete and exact text unless there's a reason you can't practically provide that. Also, while I believe this question is fully on-topic for Ask Ubuntu, https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/ may be a valuable resource. (You'd need to give more details there, too, though.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought at first that the problem was a faulty upgrade and that others would be affected and the fault quickly fixed. Now I think the error is on my machine and has something to do with the DATEVALUE function suddenly failing to recognise a text date in an altered regional format. I'm still working on it.